# Why PHP data will not transfer to PHP myadmin

Tags: php, html, sql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to create a ecommerce website where the admin user can add items. Every time an item is added, it is supposed to be brought into a SQL server via PHP myAdmin. When I completed this code, it transferred the data the first time, but has since stopped. How can I fix this problem?. Thanks in advance for any help. It is greatly appreciated. Below is my PHP code

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['insert_post'])) {

    //getting the text data from the fields
    $product_title = $_POST['product_title'];
    $product_cat = $_POST['product_cat'];
    $product_brand = $_POST['product_brand'];
    $product_price = $_POST['product_price'];
    $product_desc = $_POST['product_desc'];
    $product_keywords = $_POST['product_keywords'];


    //getting the image from the field
    $product_image = $_FILES['product_image'] ['name'] ;
    $product_image_tmp = $_FILES['product_image']['tmp_name'];

    move_uploaded_file($product_image_tmp, "product_images/$product_image");

    $insert_product = "INSERT INTO products (product_cat,product_brand,product_title,product_price,product_desc,product_image, product_keywords) values ('$product_cat', '$product_brand', '$product_title', '$product_price', '$product_desc', '$product_image', '$product_keywords')";

    $insert_pro = mysqli_query($con, $insert_product);

    if($insert_pro) {

        echo "<script>alert('Product has been inserted')</script>";
        echo "<script>window.open('insert_product.php', '_self')</script>";

    }

}


?>
```

Comment: You have a space in your assignment to `$product_image` which may be causing some issue. You're also prone to SQL injection.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. Where exactly is the space. I can't see it

Comment: You can start by checking if you are receiving the right values with print_r($_POST); print_r($_FILES);

Comment: @Isac          What would I do with the variables in the square brackets then

Comment: @Kg123 -- I was referring to `$_FILES['product_image'] ['name']`. That will likely throw a syntax error.

Comment: Your code is **_wide open_** to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Don't build queries by sticking strings together. Instead, use prepared statements with parameter binding.

Comment: i cant see $con??

Comment: @MuhammadDyasYaskur.   $con is located above in the document. It is linked to another file